# view jar file through java code

Tags: java, jar

I want to create one java application that will iterate an jar file and will give classes of that jar file.

I searched a lot but didn't get sufficient information.
I want java code that will open the jar file and will able to iterate that jar.

Answer (score 1):

See:
    java.util.jar.JarFile.entries()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#entries%28%29